# NextJS-14: How to scroll to sections - useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vite

Back then I had created an old portfolio site with Vite React + TS and used useRef for scrolling to sections from my Navbar. I would like to switch this portfolio to NextJS 14.

I dragged my old components and style folders into the /app folder and imported everything for the default home page into page.tsx.

Then I noticed: It has to be a client component with "use client" because I use useRef. But this is the top instance of my application.

Client components should actually be kept as minimal as possible. A maximum of a single button or even smaller.

If I use “use client” here, will the meaning of NextJS be lost or not?

How to do it correctly?

**page.tsx:**

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import { Navbar } from './components/Navbar'
import { Hero } from './components/Hero'
import { About } from './components/About'
import { Services } from './components/Services/Services'
import { Techstack } from './components/Techstack'
import { Contact } from './components/Contact'
import { ScrollToTop } from './components/ScrollToTop'
import { Footer } from './components/Footer'

export default function Home() {
   const servicesRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
   const aboutRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
   const contactRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

   return (
     <>
       <Navbar
     servicesRef={servicesRef} aboutRef={aboutRef} contactRef={contactRef} />
       <Hero/>
       <About ref={aboutRef}/>
       <Services ref={servicesRef} />
       <Tech stack/>
       <Contact ref={contactRef}/>
       <ScrollToTop/>
       <Footer/>
     </>
   )
}
```

**Navbar.tsx:**

```
import '../assets/styles/components/Navbar.scss';
import { Burger_Menu } from './Burger/Burger_Menu';
import { Sidebar } from './Sidebar';
import X_Logo from "../assets/images/logos/X_Logo.webp"

interface Navbar_Interface {
   aboutRef : any
   servicesRef : any,
   contactRef : any,
}

export const Navbar = ({ servicesRef, aboutRef, contactRef} : Navbar_Interface) => {
   const ScrollSection = (Section : any) => {
     const CurrentTop = Section.current.offsetTop - 70;
     window.scrollTo({behavior : "smooth", top : CurrentTop})
     /*Section.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })*/
   }

   return (
     <nav>
       <Burger_Menu/>
       <sidebar/>
       <div className="Nav_Logo_Container">
         <img src={X_Logo} className='Nav_Logo_Image'/>
         {/* Logo, SVG, or Brand Name : x.de */}
       </div>
       <div className="Nav_Links_Container">
         <div className="Nav_Links_Content"> {/* Hide On Mobile */}
           <a className="Nav_Link" onClick={()=>{window.scrollTo({behavior : "smooth", top : 0, left : 0})}}>Start</a>
           <a className="Nav_Link" onClick={()=>{ScrollSection(aboutRef) }}>About Me</a>
           <a className="Nav_Link" onClick={()=>{ScrollSection(servicesRef) }}>Services</a>
           <a className="Nav_Link" onClick={()=>{ScrollSection(contactRef)}}>Contact</a>
         </div>
       </div>
     </nav>
   )
}
```

Tried to ask in another forum and google similar questions without sucess.

Comment: You can use [element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Don't let React fool you, all you need to do is to have a reference (or be able to get one) to an element. Don't overcomplicate it, just give them known static IDs and use and call `document.getElementById().scrollIntoView(...)`. It's normally frowned upon in react, but passing refs around is arguably (and in my opinion) more complicated (as you've observed first hand here).

Comment: Thx didnt think about that but the first Problem is i cant use ScrollIntoView because my Fixed Navbar has a height of 70px and i have to give it a -70 offset and i dont know thats not the React-Way or in this case NextJS-Way. Its not always just about easyness i always want to improve my knowledge.

Comment: You can use `scrollIntoView({behaviour:'smooth',block:'start'})`, but you also need to use [scroll-padding-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-top) on your scroll container than contains your elements and setting it to the height of your navbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want without using client components :

**Page.tsx**

```
<div id="about-me"> <About/> </div>
```

**Navbar.tsx**

```
 <a className="Nav_Link" href="#about-me">About Me</a>
```

Comment: .... I thought this only works on Wordpress and is a Elementor Divi etc. Thing. Thank you, thats very time saving

Comment: Try it with the Next.js `<Link>` component too. This gives you probably an even better user experience with back button preserving scroll positions. I don't remember well (it changed over versions), but in our current app all fragment links (it's not WordPress, it is Web standard) are done with the Link component. Check it out.